# Retrieve data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I have 3 tables, want to write the select result but I don't know how to use 'join' 'inner' 'outer', etc, would be grateful if someone help me.

Tables: manufacturers / products / products_description

```
$manufacturer_query = "SELECT manufacturers_id from manufacturers WHERE manufacturers_name='" . $m ."'";
$manufacturer = mysql_query($manufacturer_query);
$mresult = mysql_fetch_array($manufacturer);

$products_query = "SELECT p.products_id, pd.products_description FROM products p, products_description pd WHERE p.products_id=pd.products_id AND p.manufacturers_id=" . $mresult['manufacturers_id'];
$products = mysql_query($products_query);
$presult = mysql_fetch_array($products);


$c = 0;                            
while ($presult){
$c++;
echo $c . ' - ' . $prod['p.products_id'] . ' - '.$prod['pd.products_description'].' - ' . $mresult['manufacturers_id'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Take a look at http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: I would help greatly if you would explain your table structure and what the query result you are looking for is.

Comment: @MikeBrant Basically the structure is easy to understand. manufacturer table give product manufacturer (I think do not need to join), products and products_description should match their products_id which is common to both and selected where manufacturer_id from products match the one from manufacturer table. I just need write down the result, as I put in a while condition (I don't know if it is correct too).

Comment: The call to `mysql_fetch_array` should be in the loop; it looks like your code will fetch only the first row. (See my answer.) Emphasizing Neal's comment above... don't use mysql_ functions. Echoing Mike Brant's comment: specifying the resultset you expect to be returned would go a long ways to figuring out the query to return that resultset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second query (`$products_query`), you already have a join.

The comma between the two table names (products and products_description) is a join operator.

This could be rewritten, replacing the comma join operator with the the `JOIN` keyword, and relocating the join predicate into an ON clause e.g.

```
SELECT p.products_id
     , pd.products_description
  FROM products p
  JOIN products_description pd
    ON pd.products_id=p.products_id
   AND p.manufacturers_id = 1
```

This is an "inner" join in that rows for `p.manufacturers_id = 1` will be returned ONLY if (at least one) row exists in the `products` table that matches that, AND if there is also at least one row in the products_description table that has a value in `products_id` that matches a row (or rows) returned from the products table.

Adding the keyword `INNER` before the `JOIN` keyword does not change the statement, it has no effect.

Given these table contents:

```
TABLE: products
manufacturers_id  products_id   
1                 222
1                 333
1                 444

TABLE: products_description
products_id    products_description
222            foo    
444            fee
444            fi
444            fo
444            fum
```

That query would return:

```
p.products_id  pd.products_description  
222            foo    
444            fee
444            fi
444            fo
444            fum
```

If you add the `LEFT` keyword before the `JOIN` keyword, then the query would be an `OUTER` join, and the query would also return a row like:

```
p.products_id  pd.products_description  
333            (NULL)
```

where a row from the table on the left side of the JOIN has no matching row found in the table on the right side.

If you want the rows returned in a particular sequence, then include an ORDER BY clause at the end of your query, e.g:

```
ORDER BY p.products_id, pd.product_description
```

Absent that, MySQL is free to return the rows in an arbitrary order.

---

The keywords `INNER` and `OUTER` are entirely optional. They have no effect on how the statement is processed, and this is why most SQL developers omit these keywords.

A `LEFT JOIN` is an `OUTER` join. Rows will be returned from the table on the left even when no matching row is found in the table on the right.

(For a cross join, we do usually include the `CROSS` keyword, even though it has no effect, just because it serves as documentation that the omission of an ON clause is intentional.)

---

The call to mysql_fetch_array should be in the loop:

```
$products = mysql_query($products_query);
$c = 0;
while ($prod = mysql_fetch_array($products) ) {
    $c++;
    echo $c . ' - ' . $prod['products_id'] . ' - '.$prod['products_description'].' - ' . $mresult['manufacturers_id'] . '<br>';
}
```

---

The mysql_ interface is DEPRECATED. New development should use either the mysqli_ or PDO interface.

Comment: Well explained, but still not working. I tried to modify some lines but nothing happened. 'p.product_id' and 'pd.products_description', returns zero and 'while' enters in a infinite loop.

Comment: moving the call to `mysql_fetch_array` inside the loop (inside the while condition) should fix your "infinite loop" problem. I had edited my answer to include this; you must not have seen that when you posted your comment.

Comment: Actually there is no infinite loop (yes, I've corrected) but p.products_id and pd.products_description are not being shown.

Comment: The problem with no data being shown by the echo is in the values of your array index constants. Those index values either need to be numeric, or need to match the name of the column in the result set. The contents of the array should be referenced (e.g.) either as `$prod[0]` and `$prod[1]`, or `$prod['products_id']` and `$prod['products_description']`

Comment: The 'while' returns correctly 700 values ($c) which means the products are in the query but both ID and Description not being shown yet despite both of them match as numeric values and column names. Any other idea?

Comment: For debugging, I would suggest including a `var_dump $prod` inside that loop, to see what indexes are in the $prod array.  (Rather than use echo, I would likely use a `printf`.)

Comment: If I write $prod['products_id'] instead of $prod['p.products_id'] I can see the result, but why? What should I do if I want to show both IDs then (from P and PD)?

Comment: Sorry was my mistake, you did right into your post. Thank you Spencer @spencer7593

Comment: mysql_fetch_array is using the column name returned from the resultset as indexes.  The `p.` and `pd.` in the query text are qualifiers. They are NOT included as part of the column name returned in the resultset metadata.  (Run the query in mysql command line client, you will see that returned column names do not include the qualifiers.)  To specify a column name to be returned for a column, give the column an alias, e.g. `SELECT p.foo AS p_foo, pd.foo AS pd_foo FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

try this with INNER JOIN

```
 $manufacturer_query = "SELECT m.manufacturers_id , p.products_id, pd.products_description FROM manufacturers m 
                        INNER JOIN  products p  ON p.manufacturers_id= m.manufacturers_id 
                        INNER JOIN  products_description pd ON  p.products_id=pd.products_id 
                        WHERE manufacturers_name='" . $m ."'";



 $products = mysql_query($manufacturer_query);
 $presult = mysql_fetch_array($products);


 $c = 0;                            
 while ($presult){
 $c++;
 echo $c . ' - ' . $prod['p.products_id'] . ' - '.$prod['pd.products_description'].' - ' . $mresult['manufacturers_id'] . '<br>';
}
```

**EDIT**

```
 $manufacturer_query = "SELECT m.manufacturers_id mm, p.products_id pp, pd.products_description  ppd FROM manufacturers m INNER JOIN 
                 products p  ON p.manufacturers_id= m.manufacturers_id INNER JOIN 
                 products_description pd ON  p.products_id=pd.products_id  WHERE manufacturers_name='" . $m ."'";



   $products = mysql_query($manufacturer_query);



  $c = 0;                            
  while ($presult = mysql_fetch_array($products)){
 $c++;
  echo $c . ' - ' . $presult['pp'] . ' - '.$presult['ppd'].' - ' . $presult['mm'] . '<br>';
  }
```

Comment: Not working. I tried to put m.manufacturers_name in the end of query, also changed the $prod to $presult in while but still not working.